# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges while connecting with sys as sysdba

Tags: oracle-10g, sysdba

I installed Oracle database 10g as an administrator on a windows 10 machine, it worked fine, but when i try to connect sys as sysdba it gives me the error:

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

I checked sqlnet.ora file and if SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES is NTS and it is:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

I added the user to the ORA_DBA group and i checked with:

```
c:\Oracle>echo %username%
```

and

```
c:\Oracle>NET LOCALGROUP ORA_DBA
```

and the user is in the group.

I don't know what else i should do, anything will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Are you connecting as

```
 sys as sysdba
```

or

```
 / as sysdba
```

?

If you are using the first option, is it prompting you for a password, and are you entering the password for the user?  Did you create a local Windows user account as the user, not the user id used to install the software?  Oracle recommends a user with administrators group install the software, and a local Windows user be defined for the sys and system accounts.

Comment: i am using "sys as sysdba" and it is not asking me for a password, and i didn't create any local windows user. I installed the software as an administrator that's all, it works in other machines (windows server 2012) i don't know about this one, the only difference other than the OS is the oracle folder is in D partition.

Comment: Hmmmm. Sorry; not sure what else to check.  It should not matter that Oracle is on d: drive; I would just check the registry key in regedit `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\KEY_*` where * is your oracle home registry folder name.

Comment: check for what in the registry?

Comment: Check if ORACLE_HOME is set to what you expect, etc.  I'm struggling through some similar issues so sorry I cannot offer more details.